# Transcluded content does not compile correctly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-directive

I need my directive's transcluded content to recompile when an attribute on the parent scope changes and then get the whole compiled HTML.

Here is the directive:

```
<custom-directive title="bla">
  <!--
   Here I iterate over the parent scope's logs variable;
   Nothing stays as result of the compilation
  -->
  <span ng-repeat="log in logs">{{ log }}</span>

 <!-- Expressions like these are evaluated fine when using $interpolate -->
 {{ 'foo' }}
</custom-directive>
```

Here is the directive's implementation:

```
{
  template: '<a class="btn">Do something</a>',
  replace: true,
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true,
  scope: {
    title: '@'
  },
  link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
    scope.$watch(function () {
      return scope.$parent.logs;
    }, function () {
      transclude(function (clone) {
        $compile(clone)(scope.$parent);

        // Now I need to use the compiled clone from here,
        // turn it into plain text and URL encode it
      });
    }, true);
  }
};
```

The problem is that any directives I am using in the transcluded HTML (i.e. in the body of the directive) are not evaluated, such as ngRepeat. If I use `$interpolate` instead of `$compile` in the link function, at least expressions in `{{ }}` are printed right, but I need the whole transcluded HTML to be compiled correctly.

In other words, my goal is to recompile the HTML inside the directive every time the parent scope's logs change, and then grab that compiled HTML and do stuff with it (I need to eventually turn it into plain text and URL encode it).

I am surprised I am having to do this manually to begin with, so my approach may just be totally wrong.

Comment: Perhaps provide a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I probably just don't fully understand the `transclude` function that I can pass to my link method; manually compiling it just didn't do it for me.

Instead, I ended up including the `ngTransclude` directive in the directive's template. That way, the transcluded content is part of the `element` inside the link function and is automatically compiled correctly.

Then I can just watch the element's text changes instead of watching a particular property on the parent scope that would change the interpolated text. It's more flexible that way if I decide to have more scope variables in the transcluded content later on.

Moral of the story: Don't mess with the `transclude` function, just use `ngTransclude` inside the template and access it on the `element` itself.

```
{
  template: '<a class="btn">Do something <div ng-transclude class="hidden"></div></a>',
  replace: true,
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true,
  scope: {
    title: '@'
  },
  link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
    scope.$watch(function () {
      return element.find('[ng-transclude]').text();
    }, function (text) {
      // do something with text here
    }, true);
  }
};
```